# How to check if predefined selected column is null is laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this code :

```
$employee_calendar->attendance = Attendance::leftJoin("attendance_corrections", function ($join) {
                $join->on("attendance_corrections.attendance_id", "=", "attendance.id")
                    ->where("attendance_corrections.status", "!=", "rejected");
            })
            ->select('attendance.*', DB::raw('IF(`time` IS NOT NULL, `time`, attendance_corrections.correct_time) as `correctTime`'))
            ->where("attendance.employee_id", $employee->id)
            ->whereDate("attendance.date", "=", $employee_calendar->date)
            ->orderBy('correctTime', 'asc')
            ->with("requests")
            ->distinct()
            ->get();
```

I want to check if correctTime is null then dont show this data. I have tried ->whereNotNull('correctTime') it is giving error say column not found.

Comment: Use it like ```->whereNotNull('attendance_corrections.correct_time')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its a derived column you have to use having clause, the best thing of the raw query is that you can use multiple types of operators such as AND, OR etc just by passing as a string.

```
->havingRaw("correctTime IS NOT NULL")
```

Comment: thanks just what I was looking for if any want to understand how it work follow this 
https://laraveldaily.com/did-you-know-about-havingraw-function/

Comment: Good Luck, with you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use it like

```
->whereNotNull('attendance_corrections.correct_time')
```

Comment: this correctTime does not belong to table as I am creating it here

DB::raw('IF(`time` IS NOT NULL, `time`, attendance_corrections.correct_time) as `correctTime`')